# Session becomes null while redirect from another page

Tags: c#, iis, windows-10, http-redirect, httpcontext

I have multi page web application in that I redirect to another page which was in another domain(wxyz.com\confirmation) from my localhost from that page again redirect to my localhost using tab id i maintain the session in last phase of the process i get the session as null anyone facing the problem like this

localhost/page1 ===> wxyz.com/confirmation  ===> localhost/page2 (In this phase I lost the session)
FYI :
I'm facing the problem for recent days (10 days) before that it working properly

Environment - Windows 10 
.Net Version 4.6.2

Is any problem in recent update of windows (don't know)

```
<html> <body> 
   <form name="FrmHtmlCheckout" method="POST" action='' > 
      <input id='field1' type='hidden' name='field1nme' value="txtValue" /> 
   </form> 

   <script language='javascript'> 
      CheckOut();
      function CheckOut(){
          document.FrmHtmlCheckout.action = 'wxyz.com/confirmation';
          document.FrmHtmlCheckout.submit();
     }
  </script> 
</body> </html>
```

Comment: Can you include the code that you are using for redirection

Comment: I'm using form POST method 

I'm not using response.redirect (url)

Comment: here is the code
`<html>
 <body>
  <form name="FrmHtmlCheckout" method="POST" action='' >
   <input id='field1' type='hidden' name='field1nme' value="txtValue" />        
  </form>
  <script language='javascript'> CheckOut();function CheckOut(){document.FrmHtmlCheckout.action = 'wxyz.com/confirmation';document.FrmHtmlCheckout.submit();}</script>
 </body>
</html>`

Comment: And which browser are you using. Since it was working before have you tried with another browser?

Comment: The java script is causing issue or you aren't giving the script the correct parameters.

Comment: @ajith I tired with different browsers also (Mozilla,chrome)

Comment: @jdweng can you elaborate what was wrong in JS.?

Comment: Either the URL is wrong or getting an exception.  I suspect there was an update to the browser that is causing the issue.  Or you switched to a different browser.  You always can use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to see what happens when it fails.

Comment: what about <httpCookies...> under <system.web> in your web.config? Could you check if session cookies are there while landing on localhost/page1? How do you check for Session[..] is null?

Comment: @yob Nope.i don't use httpCookies because of security reasons.It works fine in server environment (Windows server 2008) in local alone i'm facing problem like this.

below is the code to get session 
`public string UserName
    {
        get
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session[GetSession(Name)] == null)
                return null;
            else
                return (string)HttpContext.Current.Session[GetSession(Name)];
        }
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session[GetSession(Name)] = value;
        }
    }`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help guys finally found the solutions and root cause because of windows 10 recent update this problem occurs.For solution and changes
refer below link for more details

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-framework-december-2019-security-and-quality-rollup/